# fopen() directly from server

Tags: php, fopen

I created small loop to send e-mails with attachment (I known that the loop is not the best way to send a few mail but it's only test). The loop load e-mail and attachment name list from `.csv`. Everything works fine when attachment come from form but when I fopen file direct from web server, attached only `ATxxxx.txt` file.

```
$file = $_FILES['attachment'];
$file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$file_name        = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
$file_size        = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
$file_type        = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
$file_error       = $_FILES['attachment']['error'];

$handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");

$content = fread($handle, $file_size);

fclose($handle);

$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
```

Above code works fine but attachement come from form.

```
$file_tmp_name = $addlist_array[$k][1];
$file_size  = 1000000;
$handle = fopen("http://example.com/uploads/$file_tmp_name", "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
```

`$addlist_array` - it is array with e-mail address and attachment file name and return good value e.g. `$addlist_array[0][1] = test_blablabla.pdf`

This code doesn't work, email is delivered but the attachment is bad. All PDF files are available through the web browser.

Comment: You need `allow_url_fopen` setting to be enabled.

Comment: Small improvement: Instead of using `fopen`, `fread` and `fclose` you could just use `file_get_contents`. Though it can lead to memory issues if you want to read big files. But in your case that would `fread` anyway.

Comment: So if i use file_get_contents i will not longer need enabled allow_url_fopen ?

Comment: You will still need to enable that. Do you have error reporting on? Do you see any errors? Have you simply tried debugging what you get out of `fread`?

Comment: There is no error.(error_reporting is on). Fread return many strange char. I turn on allow_url_fopen from .htaccess but I'm not sure if my hosting allows thih parm.

Comment: Those "strange characters" are probably *your file*...!

Comment: From the very beginning I had enabled allow_url_fopen , so unfortunately the problem is somewhere else. Does anyone else have any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to define a req variable (in the second case) - $file_name. I'm sorry for the loss of your time.